# How to keep bootstrap modal from being dragged outside its parent container?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering how to stop my bootstrap modal from being to be moved outside of its parent. In short how to keep the bootstrap modal contained in its parent?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ShowValidatioResult();
});

function ShowValidatioResult() {
  $('#ValidationResultWrapper').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    show: true,
    backdrop: false
  });
  // Jquery draggable
  $('#ValidationResultWrapper .modal-dialog').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
  });
}
```

```css
#ValidationResultsWrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.modal-dialog {
  width: 400px !important;
}

#ValidationResults {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}

#ValidationResultsHeader {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#ValidationResultWrapper .modal-body {
  padding: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="ValidationResultWrapper" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header alert-primary" style="color: white; background-color: #003366; background-image: none, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Just text
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

Comment: I think this will answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163388/javascript-prevent-draggable-div-outside-parent-div

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `containment` -> https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment ...? Change code to

```js
...
).draggable({
    handle: '.modal-header',
    containment: 'window' //or another element/container
  })
}
```

Have ported the snippet to a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/axr3v9Lz/**

Comment: I am having issues now with it being dragged left or right, however though, it stays in its container going from top to bottom

Comment: let me rephrase that, it doesn't like going left, kinda has mind of its own whether it lets me drag left or right

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a solution; setting containment to window fixed it. However, as @Chris mentioned, I can't drag it left; but can drag it to right, up and down.

Comment: @NoBullMan, the modal fills the entire width of the container, thus you cannot drag it left or right (it need to be inside the container) if you set a smaller fixed width to the modal, you can drag it left and right. Hope it helps.

Comment: @davidkonrad thank you for clarification. But I can drag it right and not left. Why can I move it right but not left is baffling me.